# making this javascript more efficient?

Tags: javascript, authentication, constructor

I have this basic javascript that using a constructor, validates the form where the login fields cant be empty. All this WITHOUT using any js libraries. So far I have come up with this...

```
function Validator(txtbox) {
    this.txtbox = txtbox;
}

var validator = new Validator([ "username", "password"]);

Validator.prototype.validate = function(form) {
    for(var i = 0, l=this.txtbox.length; i < l; i++) {
        var status = document.getElementById("status-msg");
        if (form[this.txtbox[i]].value == 0) {
            status.innerHTML="The " + form[this.txtbox[i]].name + " is empty";
            status.style.display = "inline-block"
            status.className = "error";
            return false;
        }
        else {
             status.innerHTML="Login successful";
            status.style.display = "inline-block"
             status.className = "success";
        }
    }
}

function runValidate(form) {
    validator.validate(form);
}
```

I'm wondering how I can make it more efficient? Or any advice how I could make this better would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please define more efficient.

Comment: You may want to post your question at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: BenM - working in a well-organized and competent way

Comment: Thanks Alok - I didn't know about that site.

Comment: Why forbidding `"0x00000"` as password?

Comment: should I change it to null?

Answer (score 2):

You might move the DOM traversal which finds the "status-msg" element outside of the loop.

```
var status = document.getElementById("status-msg");

for(var i = 0, l=this.txtbox.length; i < l; i++) {...}
```

Right now you are traversing the DOM once for each field being validated.